# Write(Put) and Read(Get) values from Excel file using apex etc

Tags: apex

I've an excel workbook which has complex formula in multiple named ranges. I want to put some values as input data and get result from calculated formula of other named ranges. please advice if this is possible.

Comment: You might consider writing CSV files which you can import as raw data (a complete worksheet).

Comment: How is this related to Salesforce?  Please [edit] your post to include more details.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce is not suitable for what you're looking to do.

Excel files (xlsx) are complex, xml-based documents that have a variety of supporting files that are all zip compressed into a single file.

Apex (and Salesforce in general) has no functionality to work with such files, and it's a computationally complex enough task that even if you wanted to write your own code to do this, you would only be able to work on small files (think ~100 kB)

Further, the formulas in a workbook are not stored as values (unless you specifically copy and paste as a value, which means that cell will no longer be updated) and are evaluated by Excel.